# HttpHeader Duplicate Paths

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6, ihttphandler, web-config

I am using IHttpHeader to redirect 403 requests to a 404. 
This is running on a .Net 3.5 Web Forms and IIS 6 setup.

```
<add verb="*" path="products/" type="RequestCheck.NoAccessHandler, RequestCheck, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
```

The site is also running with a CMS system handled by another department, and all of their files are under a marketing folder, in which they also have a products folder.

**Directory structure**

```
\Root
    \products
    \marketing
        \products
            default.asp
```

Before I realized this marketing folder existed (we don't get to see it in development) the following code was working fine.

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        context.Response.Redirect("~/NotFound.aspx");
    }
```

We have a link in the navigation similar to this

```
http://mysite/marketing/products
```

Which of course now redirects to the NotFound.aspx page, since it is going to products/
If you navigate directly to the default.asp inside of it, you can get to the page.

The easy fix is to just update the navigation to use the following url

```
http://mysite/marketing/products/default.asp
```

**This isn't a fix for us, because they want me to handle it in code.**
So I changed my handler to the following.

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var url = context.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
        if (url.Contains("/mtgmktg/")) // ignore any requests coming for the CMS folders
        {
            return;
        }
        else // everything else gets a 404
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            context.Response.Redirect("~/NotFound.aspx");
        }
    }
```

And this...

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var url = context.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
        if (!url.Contains("/mtgmktg/")) // ignore any requests coming for the CMS folders
        {
            // everything else gets a 404
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            context.Response.Redirect("~/NotFound.aspx");
        }
    }
```

but both of these just send me to a blank page, it doesn't render anything.
Then I tried this...

***Bad Code***

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var url = context.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
        if (url.Contains("/mtgmktg/")) // ignore any requests coming for the CMS folders
        {
            context.Response.Redirect(url); // This causes an infinite loop
        }
        else // everything else gets a 404
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            context.Response.Redirect("~/NotFound.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Now it just goes to a "This page can't be displayed"

I have also tried removing the marketing folder through the config, but that just gets ignored. I tried putting this before and after my add above. neither one does anything.

```
<remove verb="*" path="marketing/" />
OR
<remove verb="*" path="marketing/products/" />
```

Does anyone have any other ideas? Remember, I cannot change the link in the navigation.

**Update 1**

The blank page is because I didn't pay attention to what I did...  The last code sample causes an infinite loop, crashing the page. So I need to rollback to one of the previous samples that are causing the blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these approaches.

1. Change the path that you use when registering the handler. Add a leading `/`

   ```
   <add verb="*"
       path="/products/"
       type="RequestCheck.NoAccessHandler, RequestCheck, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"
   />
   ```
2. Add the handler within a `<location></location>` block. The `location` block goes directly into the `<configuration></configuration>` element in the web config:

   ```
   <configuration>
       ... other stuff in the web.config ....
       <location path="products">
           <system.web>
               <httpHandlers>
                   <add verb="*"
                       path="products/"
                       type="RequestCheck.NoAccessHandler, RequestCheck, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"
                   />
               </httpHandlers>
           </system.web>
       </location>
   </configuration>
   ```

---

**Note 1**: The call to `context.Response.Redirect` overrides the status code set on the line above. What the browser ends up seeing is a 302 (=redirect) response. The line:

```
context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
```

can be removed if you are anyway going to perform a redirect...

**Note 2**: Your approach with trying to check the path and avoid redirecting in some cases will not work. If I read your question right, you want `.../marketing/products/` to be handled by `...marketing/products/Default.aspx`. But `.aspx` files are handled by a different IHttpHandler. By the time your code runs, your custom handler has already been selected as the handler for the request. IT is the responsible for generating a response. It's too late then to try to hand the request over to a different handler. So when you simply return from the `ProcessRequest` method, you are abandoning the request without sending a response. Therefore the empty page.

Comment: option 1 worked in my case, no need for option 2. I don't understand why that works, but it does. So thank you.